# Firebase - Custom Events - event data only provided for last 30 - minutes

Tags: ios, firebase, events, parameters

I want to setup custom events with parameters using Firebase and I am really struggling. So let's say, my project offers profiles, and I want to track how often profiles are visited by users.

In my iOS-project I run - exactly as it is suggested in the Firebase-documentation:

```
func visitTour(profile: Profile) {       
   /* ... */
   Analytics.logEvent("user_visited_profile", parameters: [
                "profile_id": profile.id as NSObject
                "profile_name": profile.name as NSObject 
                ])
   /* ... */
}
```

After 24hrs I could see this event listed in the firebase console, and I could add the parameters.

When I now go to my Event-Report by navigating to  **Events** -> **user_visited_profile** -> these parameter values are **only tracked** accurately in the **30-minute-event**-window. There is a parameter window for each parameter, but it doesn't display any useful information.

What I need is a table, showing **[id:visitnumber]-values** as shown in the 30-minute table but with no temporare restriction.

Any Idea how I can achieve this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
Set parameter as text (not numbers), and they will actually do show up as wished.